# EdgeSync service cannot connect to this subscription because of error "The LDAP server is unavailable."

Tags: exchange, exchange-2010, exchange-2016

I am in the middle of migrating Exchange 2010 to 2016.I've installed two Edge transport 2016 server in coexistence with 2010 one.Running `Test-EdgeSynchronization` after running `New-edgesubscription` command in Mailbox 2016 encounters `EdgeSync service cannot connect to this subscription because of error "The LDAP server is unavailable."`.Also event id 1024 appears in the event viewers.

Answer (score 0):

My problem solved by adding an A record of edge server name (edg) in the forest primary domain dns server which its suffix also is my SMTP domain and the certificate for smtp in edge server is issued to edg.domain.com .As the mailbox server is located in a child domain (mailbox.child.domain.com) rather than forest primary domain (domain.com) it could not resolve edge.domain.com. Actually we need A record of edg in both domain.com and child.domain.com

Answer (score 0):

Use following steps to resolve "LDAP server is unavailable" error:

1. Disable the Windows Firewall temporarily.
2. Use the "nslookup" command to verify DNS resolution and fix any discrepancies.
3. Make sure that all prerequisites for CU are installed or configured before starting the upgrade.
4. Test the connectivity to the AD Domain Controller using tools like AD Explorer or LDP.exe.
5. Enable GC on the LDAP or AD LDS server.
   Hope it will fix the issue, Also refer this link for more information about [LDAP Server is unavailable error](https://www.stellarinfo.com/blog/idap-server-is-unavailable/).